# pyspark dataframe transformation by grouping multiple columns independently

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Hi I am looking to convert the dataframe by grouping the columns separately and adding as new columns to existing dataframe.

```
ID  qty year    day week
1   2   2016    5   9
2   4   2016    5   9
3   0   2016    5   9
4   4   2016    5   9
5   0   2016    5   9
6   2   2016    5   9
1   0   2016    6   9
2   2   2016    6   9
3   0   2016    6   9
4   0   2016    6   9
5   0   2016    6   9
6   0   2016    6   9
1   0   2016    0   10
2   2   2016    0   10
3   2   2016    0   10
4   2   2016    0   10
5   6   2016    0   10
6   0   2016    0   10
1   0   2016    1   10
2   0   2016    1   10
3   2   2016    1   10
4   0   2016    1   10
5   0   2016    1   10
6   0   2016    1   10
1   0   2016    2   10
2   6   2016    2   10
3   0   2016    2   10
4   4   2016    2   10
5   0   2016    2   10
6   2   2016    2   10
1   0   2016    3   10
2   0   2016    3   10
3   0   2016    3   10
4   4   2016    3   10
5   0   2016    3   10
6   0   2016    3   10
1   0   2016    4   10
2   0   2016    4   10
3   2   2016    4   10
4   4   2016    4   10
5   0   2016    4   10
6   2   2016    4   10
1   4   2016    5   10
2   0   2016    5   10
3   0   2016    5   10
4   8   2016    5   10
5   0   2016    5   10
6   0   2016    5   10
1   0   2016    6   10
2   0   2016    6   10
3   0   2016    6   10
4   6   2016    6   10
5   2   2016    6   10
6   6   2016    6   10
1   0   2020    0   8
2   2   2020    0   8
3   0   2020    0   8
4   0   2020    0   8
5   0   2020    0   8
6   2   2020    0   8
1   0   2020    1   8
2   0   2020    1   8
3   0   2020    1   8
4   0   2020    1   8
5   0   2020    1   8
6   0   2020    1   8
1   0   2020    2   8
2   0   2020    2   8
3   0   2020    2   8
4   0   2020    2   8
5   0   2020    2   8
6   0   2020    2   8
1   0   2020    3   8
2   0   2020    3   8
3   0   2020    3   8
4   0   2020    3   8
5   0   2020    3   8
6   0   2020    3   8
1   0   2020    4   8
2   0   2020    4   8
3   2   2020    4   8
4   0   2020    4   8
5   0   2020    4   8
6   0   2020    4   8
5   2   2020    5   8
6   4   2020    5   8
3   4   2020    6   8
3   4   2020    0   9
```

I am trying to convert it something like this

```
ID  qty year    day week    total_Sales_year    total_sales_by_day  total_sales_week
1   2   2016    5   9   78  12  14
2   4   2016    5   9   78  12  14
3   0   2016    5   9   78  12  14
4   4   2016    5   9   78  12  14
5   0   2016    5   9   78  12  14
6   2   2016    5   9   78  12  14
1   0   2016    6   9   78  2   14
2   2   2016    6   9   78  2   14
3   0   2016    6   9   78  2   14
4   0   2016    6   9   78  2   14
5   0   2016    6   9   78  2   14
6   0   2016    6   9   78  2   14
1   0   2016    0   10  78  2   64
2   2   2016    0   10  78  12  64
3   2   2016    0   10  78  12  64
4   2   2016    0   10  78  12  64
5   6   2016    0   10  78  12  64
6   0   2016    0   10  78  12  64
1   0   2016    1   10  78  2   64
2   0   2016    1   10  78  2   64
3   2   2016    1   10  78  2   64
4   0   2016    1   10  78  2   64
5   0   2016    1   10  78  2   64
6   0   2016    1   10  78  2   64
1   0   2016    2   10  78  12  64
2   6   2016    2   10  78  12  64
3   0   2016    2   10  78  12  64
4   4   2016    2   10  78  12  64
5   0   2016    2   10  78  12  64
6   2   2016    2   10  78  12  64
1   0   2016    3   10  78  4   64
2   0   2016    3   10  78  4   64
3   0   2016    3   10  78  4   64
4   4   2016    3   10  78  4   64
5   0   2016    3   10  78  4   64
6   0   2016    3   10  78  4   64
1   0   2016    4   10  78  8   64
2   0   2016    4   10  78  8   64
3   2   2016    4   10  78  8   64
4   4   2016    4   10  78  8   64
5   0   2016    4   10  78  8   64
6   2   2016    4   10  78  8   64
1   4   2016    5   10  78  12  64
2   0   2016    5   10  78  12  64
3   0   2016    5   10  78  12  64
4   8   2016    5   10  78  12  64
5   0   2016    5   10  78  12  64
6   0   2016    5   10  78  12  64
1   0   2016    6   10  78  14  64
2   0   2016    6   10  78  14  64
3   0   2016    6   10  78  14  64
4   6   2016    6   10  78  14  64
5   2   2016    6   10  78  14  64
6   6   2016    6   10  78  14  64
1   0   2020    0   8   20  4   20
2   2   2020    0   8   20  4   20
3   0   2020    0   8   20  4   20
4   0   2020    0   8   20  4   20
5   0   2020    0   8   20  4   20
6   2   2020    0   8   20  4   20
1   0   2020    1   8   20  0   20
2   0   2020    1   8   20  0   20
3   0   2020    1   8   20  0   20
4   0   2020    1   8   20  0   20
5   0   2020    1   8   20  0   20
6   0   2020    1   8   20  0   20
1   0   2020    2   8   20  0   20
2   0   2020    2   8   20  0   20
3   0   2020    2   8   20  0   20
4   0   2020    2   8   20  0   20
5   0   2020    2   8   20  0   20
6   0   2020    2   8   20  0   20
1   0   2020    3   8   20  0   20
2   0   2020    3   8   20  0   20
3   0   2020    3   8   20  0   20
4   0   2020    3   8   20  0   20
5   0   2020    3   8   20  0   20
6   0   2020    3   8   20  0   20
1   0   2020    4   8   20  2   20
2   0   2020    4   8   20  2   20
3   2   2020    4   8   20  2   20
4   0   2020    4   8   20  2   20
5   0   2020    4   8   20  2   20
6   0   2020    4   8   20  2   20
5   2   2020    5   8   20  6   20
6   4   2020    5   8   20  6   20
3   4   2020    6   8   20  4   20
3   4   2020    0   9   20  4   20
```

I tried doing something like this but this will not get expected dataframe.

```
df.groupBy("year").agg("qty")
```

but this will only give one column and won't be able to tie it back to ID Column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **unbounded** `Window` with **only** `partitionBy` clause as shown below or you can **specify** `rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.unboundedFollowing)`.
I have tested on your data and it works fine. Let me know if it works.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w1=Window().partitionBy("year")
w2=Window().partitionBy("year","week")
w3=Window().partitionBy("year","week","day")

df.withColumn("total_Sales_year", F.sum("qty").over(w1))\
  .withColumn("total_sales_by_day", F.sum("qty").over(w3))\
  .withColumn("total_sales_week", F.sum("qty").over(w2)).show()

+---+---+----+---+----+----------------+------------------+----------------+
| ID|qty|year|day|week|total_Sales_year|total_sales_by_day|total_sales_week|
+---+---+----+---+----+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|  1|  2|2016|  5|   9|              78|                12|              14|
|  2|  4|2016|  5|   9|              78|                12|              14|
|  3|  0|2016|  5|   9|              78|                12|              14|
|  4|  4|2016|  5|   9|              78|                12|              14|
|  5|  0|2016|  5|   9|              78|                12|              14|
|  6|  2|2016|  5|   9|              78|                12|              14|
|  1|  0|2016|  6|   9|              78|                 2|              14|
|  2|  2|2016|  6|   9|              78|                 2|              14|
|  3|  0|2016|  6|   9|              78|                 2|              14|
|  4|  0|2016|  6|   9|              78|                 2|              14|
|  5|  0|2016|  6|   9|              78|                 2|              14|
|  6|  0|2016|  6|   9|              78|                 2|              14|
|  1|  0|2016|  0|  10|              78|                12|              64|
|  2|  2|2016|  0|  10|              78|                12|              64|
|  3|  2|2016|  0|  10|              78|                12|              64|
|  4|  2|2016|  0|  10|              78|                12|              64|
|  5|  6|2016|  0|  10|              78|                12|              64|
|  6|  0|2016|  0|  10|              78|                12|              64|
|  1|  0|2016|  1|  10|              78|                 2|              64|
|  2|  0|2016|  1|  10|              78|                 2|              64|
+---+---+----+---+----+----------------+------------------+----------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

**Additionally**, if you want a column `total_sales_year_to_day` you could use this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w1=Window().partitionBy("year")
w2=Window().partitionBy("year","week")
w3=Window().partitionBy("year","week","day")
w4=Window().partitionBy("year","week","day").orderBy("day")
w5=Window().partitionBy("year").orderBy("week","day")

df.withColumn("total_Sales_year", F.sum("qty").over(w1))\
  .withColumn("total_sales_by_day", F.sum("qty").over(w3))\
  .withColumn("total_sales_week", F.sum("qty").over(w2))\
  .withColumn("rownum", F.row_number().over(w4))\
  .withColumn("newday", F.when(F.col("rownum")!=1, F.lit(0)).otherwise(F.col("total_sales_by_day")))\
  .withColumn("total_sales_year_to_day", F.sum("newday").over(w5)).drop("rownum","newday").show()





+---+---+----+---+----+----------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
| ID|qty|year|day|week|total_Sales_year|total_sales_by_day|total_sales_week|total_sales_year_to_day|
+---+---+----+---+----+----------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|  1|  2|2016|  5|   9|              78|                12|              14|                     12|
|  2|  4|2016|  5|   9|              78|                12|              14|                     12|
|  3|  0|2016|  5|   9|              78|                12|              14|                     12|
|  4|  4|2016|  5|   9|              78|                12|              14|                     12|
|  5|  0|2016|  5|   9|              78|                12|              14|                     12|
|  6|  2|2016|  5|   9|              78|                12|              14|                     12|
|  1|  0|2016|  6|   9|              78|                 2|              14|                     14|
|  2|  2|2016|  6|   9|              78|                 2|              14|                     14|
|  3|  0|2016|  6|   9|              78|                 2|              14|                     14|
|  4|  0|2016|  6|   9|              78|                 2|              14|                     14|
|  5|  0|2016|  6|   9|              78|                 2|              14|                     14|
|  6|  0|2016|  6|   9|              78|                 2|              14|                     14|
|  1|  0|2016|  0|  10|              78|                12|              64|                     26|
|  2|  2|2016|  0|  10|              78|                12|              64|                     26|
|  3|  2|2016|  0|  10|              78|                12|              64|                     26|
|  4|  2|2016|  0|  10|              78|                12|              64|                     26|
|  5|  6|2016|  0|  10|              78|                12|              64|                     26|
|  6|  0|2016|  0|  10|              78|                12|              64|                     26|
|  1|  0|2016|  1|  10|              78|                 2|              64|                     28|
|  2|  0|2016|  1|  10|              78|                 2|              64|                     28|
+---+---+----+---+----+----------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```